# Using a Moment Generating Function to find a probability function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, moment-generating-functions

I'm struggling hugely with breaking down my M.G.F. into something that I can use to give me a probability function of $X$, the problem reads:

Find the probability function, $f$, of $X$ including domain given the moment generating function of $X$ is $$M_X(t) = (0.4e^{-t} + 0.6e^{t})^2$$ I know the $0.4$ and $0.6$ values are significant, but I feel powerless as to where to start. Anybody out there with the know how to lend a hand?

Comment: Can you identify e^(2t) as the MGF of some known distribution? Can you identify 1 and e^(-2t) as the MGFs of some known distributions? Now your MGF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes on value $-1$ with probability $0.4$ and value $1$ with probability $0.6$. Then $X$ has mgf $0.4e^{-t}+0.6e^{t}$.

It follows that our mgf is the mgf of the sum of two independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, each of which has the distribution described in the first paragraph.

**Alternately**, expand the square. We get $(0.4)^2 e^{-2t}+2(0.4)(0.6)e^{0\cdot t}+(0.6)^2 e^{2t}$. This is the mgf of a random variable that takes on value $-2$ with probability $(0.4)^2$, value $0$ with probability $2(0.4)(0.6)$, and $2$ with probability $(0.6)^2$.

Comment: Thank you Andre! I'm looking at my textbook and the hints are there it just wasnt as specific in what needed to follow the expansion of the square. And thanks to the geniuses behind this website, I will definitely return, hopefully somebody can learn from this question besides me. -TimC

Comment: You are welcome. The "sum of two random variables" viewpoint that I gave first is also quite useful.